# CheckBox.AutoCheck in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

What is the *easiest* alternative of making [`checkBox.AutoCheck`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.autocheck(v=vs.110).aspx)`= false` in WPF? Specifically prevent CheckBox from **changing IsChecked on click**.

`CheckBox` should **still react on clicks** (`Command` and/or `InputBindings`), but shouldn't try to change its visual state on left click or <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

I can prevent bound property change by using `Mode=OneWay`, but this seems have no effect on visual state, `CheckBox` then become checked while my property is `false`, which makes me sad...

Here is an example of checkbox:

```
<!-- make this checkbox behave as if AutoCheck = false -->
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
          Command="{Binding CommandLeftButtonOrSpace}">
    <CheckBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick"
            Command="{Binding CommandRightButton}" />
    </CheckBox.InputBindings>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: code behind? Just handle `Checked` and `Unchecked` events by setting `Checked = false;`. HTH

Comment: A check box that can't be checked? Do you *want* me to punch a baby?

Comment: @Will, I don't understand you. Do you think  question is bad or too easy? Yes, `CheckBox` what has `AutoCheck = false` behavior (from winforms): can't be checked, but can be clicked, etc. It's not a [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3648933/1997232) question. I can make a custom control, but this is not really an *easy* alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple attached behavior will do

```
public class CheckBoxBehavior
{
    public static bool GetDisableAutoCheck(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(DisableAutoCheckProperty);
    public static void SetDisableAutoCheck(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(DisableAutoCheckProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisableAutoCheckProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisableAutoCheck", typeof(bool),
        typeof(CheckBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
        {
            var checkBox = d as CheckBox;
            if (checkBox == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Only used with CheckBox");
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                checkBox.Click += DisableAutoCheck_Click;
            else
                checkBox.Click -= DisableAutoCheck_Click;
        }));

    private static void DisableAutoCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        ((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked = !((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked;
}
```

Setting like this

```
<ComboBox local:CheckBoxBehavior.DisableAutoCheck="True" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks. This made my day!

Comment: Great solution. Was looking for the attached behavior for some time.

Comment: This did not work for me.  When I do this, the CheckBox control stops honoring the value of `IsChecked`.  The other solution (subclassing the control and making `OnToggle()` a no-op) worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent it from toggling in the first place by subclassing the control (from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3723871/43534)):

```
public class OneWayCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    private class CancelTwoWayMetadata : FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        protected override void Merge(PropertyMetadata baseMetadata, DependencyProperty dp)
        {
            base.Merge(baseMetadata, dp);

            BindsTwoWayByDefault = false;
        }
    }

    static OneWayCheckBox()
    {
        // Remove BindsTwoWayByDefault
        IsCheckedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(OneWayCheckBox), new CancelTwoWayMetadata());
    }

    protected override void OnToggle()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

This also switches the binding type of `IsChecked` so that you don't need to remember to put `Mode=OneWay` on it.

Comment: Cool, I've quickly tested it and it works. Though as I said in comment, custom controls aren't counted as *easy*, so I'd personally prefer to use my [own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079966/1997232). Your is very useful though if there is some logic in bound to `IsChecked` property setter, because mine will trigger setter twice per click (may be very unwanted).

Comment: Not sure why this wouldn't be *easy* -- it takes less code both to implement and to use, and doesn't have any other side effects... :)