# Checkbox that doesn't render when clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, button, checkbox

I'm looking for this behavior:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=CreateButtonCommand}">
    <Button.Content>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"  IsHitTestVisible="false" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

But I want this look:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=CreateButtonCommand}">
    <Button.Content>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"  IsHitTestVisible="false" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
     </Button.Content>
     <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

I'm after where the CheckBox doesn't render the check when you click it, the reason for the button, because I want when the user clicks, the View Model does some work and if everything is OK, then it will update the IsChecked flag for the Checkbox.

Comment: If you set `IsHitTestVisible="false"` the not a single event will be fires and mouse wont get captured. you smply cant hit that checkbox

Comment: Okay, so what is your question? Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever specific _problem_ you are having, and a clear, precise description of what that problem is.

Comment: How do I get my second code example to fire the Command that is defined in the Button?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish what PaulMolly responded with from this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921921/a-read-only-checkbox-in-c-sharp-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your Template. It just makes no sense.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
   <Button Content="Click me" Width="80" Height="20" Command="{Binding CreateButtonCommand}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Opacity="1" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Rectangle.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"></MouseBinding>
                                </Rectangle.InputBindings>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

Comment: In your example, you have to click on the "Click me" to get the command to fire.  I would like to be able to click on the "CheckBox" to get the command to fire but not render the check.

Comment: @hhherby Updated Template. Should now do what you asked for